# How to configure nginx local redirect

Tags: nginx

I try to configure nginx to redirect request to a local folder.
here is my config:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name     localhost;
        location /test {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass  http://localhost:80/data/;
        }
```

}

drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul 15 15:42 /data

why it doesn't work ?

thanks

Comment: What error do you get when you access it?

Comment: Your code snippet makes no sense. Your webserver is running at localhost at port 80. When asked for `/test` it passes the request to the same webserver location `/data`. But there is no such location in this configuration.

Please post your whole Nginx configuration and describe what you are trying to achieve in details.

Comment: What is the exact problem? "Why doesn't it work?" doesn't help much.